# Exclude one column from row's click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code that dynamically generates rows of the table where the first column of each row is checkbox:

```js
 let tr = $("<tr class='clickable-row'></tr>");
                    tr.append(`<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>`);
                    ...
```

OnClick event displays the details of the row.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".clickable-row", function (e) {
                measurementManager.displayMeasurementsInfo(this);
            });
```

How to prevent function calling on the first column of each row?

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to prevent the measurement info from appearing when the checkbox itself is clicked, or the entire cell that contains the checkbox?

Comment: @Cory I want to prevent the entire cell

Comment: But if it just checkbox than it is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the event from propagating when the first `<td>` element is clicked. Add the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable-row td:first', function(e) { e.stopPropagation() });
```

Comment: Would it need to be the click event of the checkbox itself? This would disallow selection of the row by clicking any of the white space around the checkbox in the table cell.

Comment: Why would this disallow selection of the row? I didn't see any mention of row selection in the question? Also, the click even on the checkbox will propagate up anyway.

Comment: Poor wording. I'm guessing OP's issue is that clicking the checkbox causes the "measurements info" to appear for that row, which is the behavior they're trying to fix. It would be a question of whether they want to stop that behavior for clicking directly on the checkbox, or on the entire cell. I have asked OP for clarification.

Comment: @BenM I have added your code just after: $(document).on("click", ".clickable-row", function (e) {... }); but it doesn't work. To make it more clear, I have a table where you can check a row or a few and do smth with them or you can click (probably double-click but I do not think it maters though) a row and window with information opens. I don't want to show info when checkbox (that is the first column) clicked

Comment: If I set '.checkbox' instead of '.clickable-row td:first' then it works for checkboxes but not for an entire cell that is fine with me.